# White shadow on my question

Tags: discussion

Dear users I ask you the reason because my new inserted question has a white shadow as shown in the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `support` tag is in your list of ignored tags. Remove it and you'll see it at full opacity.

Comment: @Sebastiano If this problem was not present earlier, this means someone - most likely you - added this tag to your list of ignored tags.